# How to increase the scrollback buffer size for tty

Tags: debian, grub2, tty

I have a fresh debian jessie server installed in a virtual machine and I want to be able to scroll back with Shift+PageUp and see the full long output of commands like "apt search browser". At the moment I can only see about 5 pages worth of scrolling.

I tryied the following to increase the scrollback buffer size:

- Adding `fbcon=scrollback:1024k` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in `/etc/default/grub` then doing a `update-grub`, as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/709697/how-to-increase-scrollback-lines-in-ubuntu14-04-2-server-edition and https://askubuntu.com/questions/790804/how-to-set-unlimited-scrolling-on-a-tty
  ; However after updating the grub and rebooting the scrollback buffer has the same size. What else should I do to be able to scrollback longer?

UPDATE: I found out that I have no framebuffer enabled (there is not /dev/fb0 available) ... now I try to figure out how to enable it

Comment: @switch87 what do you mean with updates? I have a fresh system and I am trying to increase the buffer so I can scroll longer upwards by pressing Shift+PageUp several times

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out I did not have any framebuffer active on my machine (there was no device under `/dev/fb0`), so I tryied to mount a driver for a framebuffer.

I got a working framebuffer installing the `v86d` emulator (which is required by `uvesafb` framebuffer driver) then enabling the uvesafb driver with `modprobe uvesafb`.

At this point when I had a framebuffer at `/dev/fb0` I noticed that the scrollback range increased.

In order to have changes permanent at boot time I did the following:

- created a new configuration file under `/etc/modules-load.d/uvesafb.conf` containing the string `uvesafb`. This module will be loaded at boot time from now on.
- edited the grub configuration file located at `/etc/default/grub` and added `fbcon=scrollback:1024k` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` option then a `update-grub`. Later I noticed that a 1024KB scrollback buffer was not enough for my needs and I increased it to 4096KB.

Comment: Hi there, sorry to bother you, would you mind dumbing down/precising what is needed to do, for less experienced users ? I'm on an ArchLinux bare install in a VM and would like to have a bigger scrollback like you. I tried to follow your answer and install a package called `v86d` but the package manager doesn't know it. In any case, I'm still a bit lost as to what to do then, even if I was able to install it.

Comment: hi @Atralb , I spawned an arch virtual machine and things are much more easier than the way I did it on debian. You need to do only the last part with grub editing. Which in Arch is like this: `nano /etc/default/grub` edit like I describe above, then `grub.mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Use 4096k to have a really long scrollback, default is only 32k according to Arch Wiki. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console

Answer (score 2):

Many command-line programs write to standard output, which means you can do something like this to log the output:

```
apt search browser >> ~/my-log.log
```

But, a more transparent approach is to use the logging capabilities of a terminal multiplexor.

For example, with `tmux` you can do the following:

1. From a terminal run `tmux`, which will produce a new shell within the utility.
2. Assuming tmux default keyboard bindings, press `CTRL-b`, then `SHIFT:` (hold SHIFT and press colon). That will put you in tmux's command mode.
3. Type `pipe-pane -o 'cat >> ~/my-log.log'` and press `ENTER`.
4. Run whatever commands you want within that tmux pane; they'll get logged to `~/my-log.log`.

Comment: thanks for this workaround, I could also use the less command but I am not looking for a workaround, I want to be able to scroll through the output

Comment: With tmux you can adjust the size of a pane's buffer, allowing you to scroll back. This is separate from the logging I mentioned. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760281/how-to-increase-scrollback-buffer-size-in-tmux